# Return type for Java Hashmap while using wildcards

Tags: java, generics, hashmap, wildcard

I've got a class called Identifier and some other classes called Variable, Scalar etc which all extend from Identifier.

So when I declare a new Hashmap like:

```
Hashmap<String, ? extends Identifier> hm = new Hashmap<String, ? extends Identifier>();
```

what will the return type be when I call:

```
hm.get(String)
```

because obviously something like this isn't valid:

```
(? extends Identifier) temp = hm.get(String);
```

I don't really know a solution to this without doing some type casting or using a generic Object as the type, both of which I don't want to do.

Comment: That's the point of `?`. You don't know exactly. It can at most be an `Identifier`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't know. What you do know is that it is of type `Identifier` and that's all you should assume about this situation.

```
public Identifier getValue(string value) {
    return hm.get(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have a problem before you get to `get`, with the instantiation of the map.  You can't instantiate a type with a wildcard:

```
//                  Can't do this!
new Hashmap<String, ? extends Identifier>()
```

Because you likely don't care which type of `Identifier` you can store, just eliminate the wildcard entirely:

```
HashMap<String, Identifier> hm = new HashMap<String, Identifier>();
```

(This will also allow to to use the `put` method, without which there won't be a point to `get` later.)

and

```
Identifier temp = hm.get(someString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, it *is* pretty much a `(? extends Identifier)`. Of course, you're right that you can't write that. But think what that really means: "some type that's a subtype of `Identifier`". In other words: `Identifier`! (Remember, a type is a subtype of itself).

```
Identifier temp = hm.get(String);
```